# Create moment from epoch

Tags: typescript, date, momentjs

I want to use moment for managing time.

For that, I want to parse a string into moment and then convert it to milliseconds.

I'm doing it like so:

```
const str = "1:12.123"; // 1m, 12s, 123ms = 72123ms
const parsed = moment(str, "m:ss.SSS");
```

The problem is that this method creates a moment from "today", not from epoch.

```
console.log(parsed); // moment("2018-10-27T00:01:12.123")
console.log(parsed.unix()); // 1540609272, not 72123
```

Is there a way to parse a string from epoch and not from today? Or to accomplish what I want, I have to parse the string to number myself and convert it to milliseconds by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `moment` is a timestamp, what you need is a `duration`. From Moment.js' [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

> ... a moment is defined as single points in time, durations are defined as a length of time. Durations do not have a defined beginning and end date.

So using one of Moment.js' `duration` objects:

```
const d = moment.duration('0:1:12.123');
console.log(d.asMilliseconds());
```

Notice the leading `0:` in the string, that is the number of hours, which is required so `moment.duration` can understand the format in which you are passing the string.

Check the documentation here: [Moment.js | Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/milliseconds/)

## Foot note:

You mentioned the epoch as if it were January 1 of the year 0, notice in computers when we talk about the epoch it's usually the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): 1970-01-01. So asking for the milliseconds from the epoch would give you a lot more years than desired.

Comment: Thank you. Although I cannot make my application dynamic, it can solve for now.

Comment: Regarding the epoch, I didn't mentioned it like Jan 1 of year 0. I really meant 1970. If moment was created from epoch, when I do `moment(...).unix()`, it would give me the "diff" from epoch, thus it'd be "small" and correct. The problem with the current approach is that `moment("15", "m")` means `today` (aka `DD/MM/YYYY`) + `15min`. But there is not "easy" way to get this "today" date without some "hacking"

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant.